# Solidity transaction with an unsigned transaction object

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js, web3py

I need to interact with another smart contract from my smart contract (several times),
I have a transaction object that can be used with web3js or web3py, like this:

```
{
  from: '0x00000000',
    to: '0x0000000000',
      value: '1000000000000',
      data: '0x000000000000000000000000',
      gasPrice: '245000000000',
      gas: '163502',
      chainId: 3
}
```

how can I execute this transaction in solidity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the low-level `.call()` member of type `address`. More precisely of its extension `address payable`, since you're setting `value`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external {
        address to = payable(address(0x0));
        bytes memory sendData = new bytes(12); // empty 12 byte array
        to.call{value: 1000000000000, gas: 163502}(sendData);
    }
}
```

Note that you cannot affect the `gasPrice` as its already set in the main transaction (executing the `foo()` function).

`from` is always going to be the caller contract (in this case the `MyContract`) address.

Also, EVM-compatible contracts are not able to perform cross-chain requests - that's why you cannot specify the `chainId` either.

If you need to be able to affect any of these 3 properties, you'll need to send the transaction from an off-chain app - not from a contract.